# In-app Billing Android Issue BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I have uploaded one apk to the alpha channel with just billing permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

The uploaded apk does not have purchase flow code but I have added that code for testing apk.

Both apk signed with same credentials and has same version name and version code and also I have published subscription product on play console.

I am able to fetch SKU details but while starting purchase flow getting BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR.

Is it necessary to use same APK(same code) for testing which is uploaded to alpha channel?
and again next time if I changed something, do I need to upload it to first alpha channel and test updated code with the same apk?

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't matter what is APK. But make sure you are using same version.
Also you can't test subscription. I.e. you should only use BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP